# Flow.take(ITEM_COUNT) returning all the elements rather then specified amount of elements

Tags: kotlin, operators, kotlin-flow

I've a method X that's getting data from the server via pub sub. This method returns a flow. I've another method that subscribes to the flow by method X but only wants to take the first 3 values max from the flow if the data is distinct compared to previous data. I've written the following code

```
fun subscribeToData() : Flow<List<MyData>> {
    ....
    //incoming data
    emit(list)
}

fun getUptoFirst3Items() {
   subscribeToData()
   .take(ITEM_COUNT) // ITEM_COUNT is 3
   .distinctUntilChange() //only proceed if the data is different from the previous top 3 items
   .mapIndex {
     //do transformation
   }
   .collect { transformedListOf3Elements ->
    
   }

}
```

**Problem:**

In collect{} I'm not getting 3 elements but rather I'm getting all the data that's coming in the flow.

I'm not sure what's wrong here? Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you please share more of the implementation of `subscribeToData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `Flow<List<MyData>>` here, which means every element of this flow is itself a list.

The `take` operator is applied on the flow, so you will take the 3 first lists of the flow. Each individual list is not limited, unless you use `take` on the list itself.

So the name `transformedListOf3Elements` is incorrect, because the list is of an unknown number of elements, unless you filter it somehow in the `map`.

Answer (score 0):

@Joffrey answer already explained why you get the whole list returned and suggested you use `take()` on the list itself.

If you want to take just the first `ITEM_COUNT` elements from every list that is emitted/observed, then you have to map the result and only take `ITEM_COUNT` items from the list each time, instead of taking `ITEM_COUNT` items from the flow.

```
fun getUptoFirst3Items() {
   subscribeToData()
   .map {
     // in Kotlin stdlib Iterable<T> has an extension method take(n: Int)
     // that will return a List<T> containing the first n element from the iterable
     it.take(ITEM_COUNT)
     // alternatively you can also use subList, but the semantics are not the same,
     // so check the subList documentation, before using it
     it.subList(0, ITEM_COUNT)
   }
   .distinctUntilChange() //only proceed if the data is different from the previous top 3 items
   .mapIndex {
     //do transformation
   }
   .collect { transformedListOf3Elements ->
    
   }

}
```